# POST and GET method in the same call (Slim PHP Framework)

Tags: php, post, get, slim, http-method

Anyone could tell me how can I send a GET and POST method in the same call using Slim Framework?
What I'm trying to do is to create a call like:

```
    http://mywebserver.com/api/sync/google
```

The last parameter in this call (google) is a variable where i can set different services identified as String; I also want to send via POST the user data when calling this URL, I was trying so many things and I can't get it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, unless I'm missing something, all you need to do is submit a form POST to that URL.

Answer (score 2):

> Anyone could tell me how can I send a GET and POST method in the same
>   call...

You can't make a GET and POST request in the same "call" - a request has a single method, that is how HTTP works.

See [Hypertext Transfer Protocol 1.1 Method Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: I was suspecting that this is not possible because of HTTP protocol definition, so thank you very much for clarifying it to me.